# How to read in a text file, create a dictionary, read in another text file and translate it with said dictionary and write it into a new file

Tags: python

hey guys so I'm working on a (for me) complicated code and I'm kinda stuck. The task is that I should write a programm which **reads in a dictionary** (file.txt is given), and **translate another text** with this dictionary (also given so it must be read in too) and then **save the translated** text into a new file (which I gotta create).

I think I got it so far that the dictionary is read in but then I'm pretty much lost. I was trying to do an if loop conditional (if the key is in the text I gotta translate, it should be replaced by the value) but I can't go on from there.

So here's what I got so far:

```
dictionary = {}

with open("dict.txt") as dict:
    for line in dict:
        wordPair = line.split()
        dictionary[wordPair[0]] = wordPair[1]

def get_translations(dict):
    dict = get_translations("dict.txt")
    return get_translations(dict)

def translate(dict, text1, trnsl):
    with open("text1.txt") as text1, open("trnsl.txt", "w") as trnsl:
        for wordPair in dict:
            if wordPair == True: #that's where I can't figure it out.
```

Sidenote: if any word can't be translated from the given dictionary (because it's not part of the dictionary), it should be indicated by these "<>". I guess a simple else: print word + "<>" would do?

Thanks for ANY suggestions!

Comment: please walk through what you think `get_translations` does because i doubt it does what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify if there's punctuation or stuff.

I'm going to assume just spaces and words.

```
def translate(dict, text1, trnsl):
    with open("text1.txt") as text1, open("trnsl.txt", "w") as trnsl:
        for line in text1: # parse each line
            words = line.split() # break line into words, do more stuff here if punctuation
            for word in words:
                if word in dict: # check if translatable
                    trnsl.write(dict[word]) # get translation
                else:
                    trnsl.write(word)
                trnsl.write(' ') # re-add spaces between words
            trnsl.write('\n') # re-add endlines between lines
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use dict as a variable name as it will stop on the built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be looping through the dictionary like this in order to obtain the key and the value of each item:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    # Do something with the key or the value here.
```